# Bluetooth suddenly stops working and can't be restarted on Win 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, bluetooth

My Bluetooth mouse on Windows 8.1 drops for an unknown reason after a reboot. I searched extensively online / here / forums for fixes, all to no avail.

- I've replaced the battery
- ran all manner of CMD / POWERSHELL commands to restart it
- restarted the computer
- restarted Bluetooth Support Service

When I reboot the computer it works, but only briefly, before dropping out again. When I attempt to start the Service 'Bluetooth Driver Management Service' I get the following error dialog:

"The Bluetooth Driver Management Service service on Local Computer started and then stopped. Some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs."

Thank you for any advice / pointers.

Comment: Look in Device Manager and see if Bluetooth has a hardware issue. Seems reasonable given the age of the computer.

Comment: To see if it's OS or hardware causing the issue, try booting from USB, e.g., Ubuntu Live, https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started. If that works, it's Windows and/or drivers causing the issue, and it might be incentive to move off an unsupported OS which has not been updated, even for security patches, for over a year.